Why is Facebook graph API not returning an access token for Facebook Page added to Meta Business Suite/Business Portfolio
I have created a page named Test 1. When I go to Business Suite, my Business Portfolio and add the page Test 1 to Account -> Pages. After adding the page successfully I see page access section where I have full control over the page Test 1.
But after giving permission to the page Test 1 from the Developer app I am unable to generate page information like Page name, page id, access token etc... But when I remove the page from Meta Business Suit/Business Portfolio and again give the permission to the page from the developer app then I am able to generate the page details like access token, name and id.
My question is why I am unable to generate page details from graph api if the page is added to facebook business portfolio?
I have tried multiple time, but when the page is added to Meta Business Portfolio then I am unable to generate page details like id,name and access token

Create a System User in the Business Suite and give it the necessary permissions and assign this System User to your Facebook App.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
